# How to match/compare two dataframes searching for similar columns/rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have two dataframes:

df1 =

| CRATER_ID | LAT_CIRC_IMG | LON_CIRC_IMG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-1-000003 | 79.257599 | 211.909949 |
| 01-1-000004 | 78.696512 | 207.162344 |
| 01-1-000012 | 77.791422 | 186.586023 |
| 01-1-000013 | 76.655040 | 194.807812 |
| 01-1-000014 | 76.976285 | 195.615795 |

df2 =

```
CRATER_ID            
02-000239                
02-000311                             
02-000320               
02-000325                       
02-000443                       
   ...                         
25-002058                        
25-002387                        
25-002484                      
25-002650                 
26-001661
```

I need to search for the Crater_IDs from df2 in df1, but as you can see the numbers don't match perfectly, bc in df2 the middle numbers are missing.
I need a Code that gives me a third dataframe with all Crater_IDs and Coordinates (like df1) but only with the IDs from df2.
I already tried regular expressions and some other stuff but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to rework your CRATER_ID from df1:

```
# remove dash+number (only 1st occurrence)
df1['CRATER_ID'].str.replace(r'-\d+', '', n=1, regex=True)
```

output:

```
0    01-000003
1    01-000004
2    01-000012
3    01-000013
4    01-000014
Name: CRATER_ID, dtype: object
```

Then replace it in df1 or use it directly to merge:

```
df1.merge(df2,
          left_on=df1['CRATER_ID'].str.replace('-\d+', '', n=1, regex=True),
          right_on='CRATER_ID'
         )
```

output: None here as no match with the provided sample.